# how i can loops thourgh column in each row using python

Tags: python, pandas

Hey you guy I got a dataframe like this

```
empoyees = [('jack', 34, 'Sydney',800) ,
       ('Riti', 31, 'Delhi',800) ,
       ('Aadi', 16, 'New York',800) ,
       ('Mohit', 32,'Delhi',1500) ,
        ]
empDfObj = pd.DataFrame(empoyees, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City',Salary], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

how I can loop through columns in each row and get the result like this using pandas in python. Maybe add all it into a small list of each row

```
a Name jack Age 34 City Sydney Salary 800
b Name Riti Age 31 City Delhi Salary 800
c Name Aadi Age 16 City New York Salary 800
d Name Mohit Age 32 City Delhi Salary 1500
```

Comment: What have you found by reading the Pandas documentation or doing Google searches?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with orient set to `'index'`

The output of dict would be of the form:

```
{ idx1 : {col1:val1, col2:val2 ... coln:van},
  idx2 : {col1:val1, col2:val2 ... coln:valn},
  ...
}
```

Loop through the dict and create a list of strings if would like to store them as a list.

```
[
    f'{idx} {" ".join([str(v) for t in vals.items() for v in t])}'
    for idx, vals in df.to_dict("index").items()
]

# output
# ['a Name jack Age 34 City Sydney Salary 800',
#  'b Name Riti Age 31 City Delhi Salary 800',
#  'c Name Aadi Age 16 City New York Salary 800',
#  'd Name Mohit Age 32 City Delhi Salary 1500']
```

If you only want to print them you don't need to build a list of strings. You could do:

```
for idx, vals in df.to_dict('index').items():
    print(idx, *[v for t in vals.items() for v in t], sep=" ")

#output
# a Name jack Age 34 City Sydney Salary 800
# b Name Riti Age 31 City Delhi Salary 800
# c Name Aadi Age 16 City New York Salary 800
# d Name Mohit Age 32 City Delhi Salary 1500
```

Comment: Thanks you Bro :D that mean a lot to me

Comment: Hi Bro, I got the question. How can i get list with a form like this [(jack,age,34),(jack,city,sydney),(jack,Salary,800).....]

Answer (score 0):

i kept it simple

```
s=''
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if index in s:
        pass
    else:
        s+=str(index)
    for key, value in row[:].items():
        s+=" "+ key+" "+str(value)
    print(s)
    s=''
```

output

```
a Name jack Age 34 City Sydney Salary 800
b Name Riti Age 31 City Delhi Salary 800
c Name Aadi Age 16 City New York Salary 800
d Name Mohit Age 32 City Delhi Salary 1500
```

Comment: Thanks you Bro :D